# Summation Problem $S_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}{6^{k-2}(-k+n+2)}$

Tags: summation

How would one even go about simplifying this summation.
I understand that you can distribute the $6^{k-2}$ and separate it into 3 summations but what next?

$$S_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}{6^{k-2}(-k+n+2)}\ , n\geq2$$

Comment: you can put $(n+2)$ out of the summation it is constant, then use $\sum kx^{k-1}$ is the derivative of $\sum x^k$ this is a classic.

Comment: Note that the first summation will be an "Aritmetico-geometric " progression(AGP) while the other two are just GPs

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\ ...\ + x^n= \frac{x^n-1}{x-1} $$
Differentiate both sides. On the left hand side you get:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{ix^{i-1}} $$

This is also called arithmetico Geometric Progression.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{k=2}^n6^{k-2}(-k+n+2)$$

$$36S=-\sum_{k=2}^nk6^k+(n+2)\sum_{k=2}^n 6^k$$

**HINT for the first sum(AGP):**

$$\text{Let }\sum_{k=2}^nk6^k=S_1$$

$$S_1=2.6^2+3.6^3+4.6^4+....n.6^n$$

$$6S_1=2.6^3+3.6^4+....+(n-1)6^n+n.6^{n+1}$$

$$\implies -5S_1=2.6^2+(6^3+6^4+...+6^n)-n6^{n+1}$$

which is now very easy to evaluate

Answer (score 0):

The expanded sum is

$$S_n:=n+6(n-1)+6^2(n-2)+\cdots6^{n-3}3+6^{n-2}2.$$

Then simplifying term-wise (diagonally),

$$6S_n-S_n=
\\6n+6^2(n-1)+6^3(n-2)+\cdots6^{n-2}3+6^{n-1}2
\\-n-6(n-1)-6^2(n-2)-\cdots6^{n-3}3-6^{n-2}2
\\=6-n+6^2+6^3+\cdots6^{n-2}+6^{n-1}2$$

or

$$5S_n=6-n+\frac{6^{n-1}-6^2}{6-1}+6^{n-1}2
\\=\frac{11}{30}6^n-\frac65-n.$$